# Parse SDK Crash reporting not reporting

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, cocoapods

I'm trying to get the crash reporting to work in my app. I can't get any crash reports in my dashboard. I'm using swift 2.0, Xcode 7.1.1 and I've installed Parse v1.9.1 using cocoapods. The report navigator shows no errors and everything is successfully run:

```
Uploading iOS symbol files...

Uploaded symbol files.

Touch MyParseApp.app

ProcessProductPackaging 

Copying Swift standard libraries into MyParseApp.app

Process product packaging

Sign MyParseApp.app

Validate MyParseApp.app

Build succeeded
```

I've used the Run Script Phase suggested in the quick step guide:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH cd /Users/osl/Projects/MyParseApp/ParseCloudCode parse symbols -p "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

My cloud code directory "ParseCloudCode" in my Xcode project directory contains these files:

```
.parse.local
{
  "applications": {
    "MyParseApp": {
      "applicationId": "******************************"
    },
    "_default": {
      "link": "MyParseApp"
    }
  }
}

.parse.project
{
  "project_type": 1,
  "parse": {
    "jssdk": "latest"
  },
  "email": "*****@*****.com"
}
```

and I created i by using the `parse new` command in my Xcode project directory. I then choose my existing Parse application that I wanted to report the crashes to.

Is there something I'm missing when setting up my cloud code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will remove the Parse crash reporting tool in my app since Parse. I recived this information from Parse:

> Hi there,
>
> At Parse, we're always working to improve your developer experience.
>   Last December, we launched Parse Crash Reporting with the goals of
>   recognizing, tracking, and ultimately resolving crashes in your app.
>
> In the time since, we've seen huge strides being made within the
>   industry's native solutions. These native experiences have the
>   advantage of being more tightly integrated into your build and release
>   process, offering a more robust, streamlined, and frictionless
>   development experience for you.
>
> The Parse Crash Reporting tool is now being deprecated in favor of
>   these great native solutions. We will continue supporting Parse Crash
>   Reporting until March 1, 2016.
>
> Here's how you can smoothly switch from Parse Crash Reporting to Apple
>   or Google's offerings:
>
> [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRonuKXPZKXonjHpfsX86%2B8qWaSzlMI%2F0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4ASMNhI%2BSLDwEYGJlv6SgFTbHGMblmy7gNUxU%3D) |
>   [Google Docs](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRonuKXPZKXonjHpfsX86%2B8qWaSzlMI%2F0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4ASMNhI%2BSLDwEYGJlv6SgFTbHGMblmy7gNUxU%3D#reviews-reports)
>
> We're constantly tackling new challenges to
>   help you build better than ever before. Please reach out if you have
>   any questions or concerns to community@parse.com.
>
> The Parse Team